# Use renderer for ExtJS form field

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm trying to create a PercentField component that extends `textfield` for use on ExtJS forms. The behavior I'm looking for is for the field to display percent values, e.g. `25%` or `400%`, but have the underlying value when the user is editing the field or the form is being submitted be a decimal, e.g. `.25` or `4`.

I've succeeded in getting this working by using a renderer in a grid column, ([Here's a fiddle)](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/avu) but it doesn't look like `textfield` has a renderer property for using the field in basic forms. I've looked at the `rawToValue` and `valueToRaw` methods, but they don't seem to be quite what I'm looking for. Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no possibility of template for form fields. That would require to flip the input element and display a div or something, on focus and blur. That would be doable, but that implies some fine tuned CSS.

A simpler option is to implement custom `valueToRaw` and `rawToValue` methods, and let Ext handles the value lifecycle (which is really the complicated part). You'll still have to change the *raw* value on focus and blur, but that remains pretty straightforward.

Here's an example you can build upon (see [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/b0v)):

```
Ext.define('My.PercentTextField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',

    onFocus: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var v = this.getValue();
        if (Ext.isNumeric(v)) {
            this.setRawValue(this.rawToValue(v));
        }
    },

    onBlur: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var v = this.getValue();
        if (Ext.isNumeric(v)) {
            this.setRawValue(this.valueToRaw(v));
        }
    },

    valueToRaw: function(v) {
        return Ext.isEmpty(v) 
            ? '' 
            : v * 100 + ' %';
    },

    rawToValue: function(v) {
        // cast to float
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(v)) {
            var pcRe = /^(\d*(?:\.\d*)?)\s*%$/,
                dcRe = /^\d*(?:\.\d*)?$/,
                precision = 2,
                floatValue,
                match;
            if (match = dcRe.test(v)) { // decimal input, eg. .33
                floatValue = v * 1;
            } else if (match = pcRe.exec(v)) { // % input, eg. 33 %
                floatValue = match[1] / 100;
            } else {
                // invalid input
                return undefined;
            }
            floatValue = Number.parseFloat(floatValue);
            if (isNaN(floatValue)) {
                return undefined;
            } else {
                return floatValue.toFixed(precision);
            }
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it's working really well. I also added an override of `getSubmitValue` to handle submission.